# How do Pokémon "Sightings" work?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the new update, we now have "Sightings." However, there is no indication of how this differs from "nearby Pokémon", though in the patch notes, it states they are testing a variation of "Nearby Pokémon" which appears to be the "Sightings." How do "Sightings" differ from "Nearby Pokémon"?

[image]

Comment: If what I see is true, they no longer show dups. I was so tired of seeing 9 Pidgeys near by all the time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nearby system was originally supposed to show you pokemon spawns in order of distance (Which we all know didn't work at all). Essentially Sightings is now a list of what pokemon are currently in the area as opposed to listing every nearby spawn as an individual pokemon, which also caused a bunch of duplicates to clutter the tab. They also took out the ability to "watch" a pokemon since that was based on distance as well. Sightings doesn't appear to sort pokemon in any particular order, at least not alphabetically or numerically based on pokedex number. (For example mine currently shows Drowzee #96, Weedle #13, Ratata #19, Pidgey #16 etc.)

It also seems to update more frequently and accurately, every 15 seconds. Previously with the nearby system I would have to force close the app and reopen it to load a new nearby list (Personally I don't think it was properly removing pokemon from the list if they despawned). The new sightings system removes pokemon that are no longer currently in the area. This combined with the fact that there are no more duplicate listings, means the tab is less cluttered and more reliably showing what is actually around you.

Comment: I can attest to the old one not removing Pokémon that were no longer in the area. So basically the new one is taking the pieces that kind of worked in the old one and adding a slightly different UI around it.

Comment: Sightings do sort by distance as far as I tested. Also, your last paragraph is correct -- the non removal was a bug that was fixed in 0.33

Comment: It doesn't sort by distance. I had a list of 5/6 this morning, and a Venonat popped up right outside my house, but it was 5th in the list (i.e. the centre position). Still no decent sorting

Comment: Well actually I think it sorts by something like distance or by distance zones. It actually now shows the pokemon you just spot by you on big map and it actually is in the 3 "top" shown in small panel, so I would say it sorts them by distance. At least it seems. However it is still probably highly experimental, I hoped that the "grass" will change color or picture depending on biome, but no. And yes, it updates pretty fast, especially when you catch pokémon, it instantly hides. So let's see what they will do with it :)