# How does the nearby tab work in Pokemon Go (after 2nd update)?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the new Pokemon Go update (on 8/8/16), the nearby tab's functionality has been changed significantly. Rather than the old 'tracker' with footsteps*, there is now a page that shows 'Sightings' and 'Nearby.'

I found this question: [How do Pokémon "Sightings" work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280785/how-do-pok%C3%A9mon-sightings-work), which explains how sightings work. However, I still do not understand how the nearby tab works. I took a screenshot from my phone today:

[image]

You can see the 'Sightings' at the bottom of the tab, which are described in the above linked question. What I do not understand is the 'nearby' section. In the above example, it appears that a Goldeen is paired with a picture of a location. Does that mean that a Goldeen is nearby? If so, how is that different from the 'sightings' section?

Please do not confuse this question with [How do Pokémon "Sightings" work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280785/how-do-pok%C3%A9mon-sightings-work), as they are meant to be different. That question asks specifically about 'sightings,' while I am asking about the 'nearby' feature.

*the first update got rid of the footsteps, but kept the function of the nearby tab largely the same

Comment: The Goldeen appears to be in front of a Pokestop picture, was/is there a lured Pokestop nearby?

Comment: @TrentHawkins No, there were not any lured PokeStops nearby, to the extent of my knowledge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can click on that image of goldeen. The box will close and the map will notify you where the goldeen is.

[image]