# Difference between old Nearby and new Sightings?

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently, Pokemon Go released an update featuring a reworked Pokemon detection system -- changing "Nearby" to "Sightings".

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearby now shows the pokemon *near* a pokestop. Sightings shows pokemon that are surrounding you.

As you can see here: [How does the nearby tab work in Pokemon Go (after 2nd update)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281001/how-does-the-nearby-tab-work-in-pokemon-go-after-2nd-update)